# How do I show the automatic discounted price of a product on the product page?

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'd like to show both prices of an item, the one with an automatic discount applied as well as the original price. I have done this before manually, whenever the discount amount would change from 20% to 30% or such, I'd have to change it in multiple snippets and sections.

How would I go about fetching the automatic discount amount in percentage on the product page or any other page except the cart and checkout?

Answer (score 0):

The new Shopify functions feature that handles automatic/code discounts is designed to trigger upon cart changes. As a result, the discounted amount is intended to be visible exclusively on the cart and checkout pages. This behavior is by design, and currently, there is no built-in way to directly display the discounted amount on other pages using this feature.

Comment: Thank you! It is unfortunate and I don't really understand why, but nevertheless thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @cptmustard There is a walk-around for this, You can fetch the meta of the discount and see the percentage or amount of that discount and then use that amount to show discount on products i.e Leading you to change theme code and create another app for getting the discount meta since admin api cannot be exposed to frontend.